# Stripe - Charge connected standard account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm pretty new to Stripe, and I tried charging a connected Standard account using this code:

```
$charge = Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $account // acct_xxxxxxxxx
));
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't work and throws this error:

```
Can not transfer funds from a Standard account.
```

What can I do? What is the right way of doing that?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you are trying to do here? Charge the a standard account (with funds going to your platform), or create a charge that moves fund *TO* a standard account. Debiting an account is only available with custom or express accounts. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits

Comment: @duck I'm trying to charge a standard account, with funds going to my platform, as you said. Actually, I prefer a direct charge on the credit card instead of asking the user for an account, if possible.

Comment: Alright! If you're trying to charge a standard account, unfortunately that doesn't seem possible atm. The best option would be to prompt the user for card details, create a `Customer` on your platform, which you could then charge.

Comment: @duck can u please reference me to the appropriate docs about creating customers and charging them?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer
https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

Answer (score 0):

This feature, not available for stripe standard platform if you want to use then change your platform standard to express/custom.

Thanks,
Shani